# Where to start with Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm new to Ethereum

I just installed the Ethereum Wallet and Solidity on my Linux system. Before I installed everything I read the whole documentation of Ethereum and Solidity. Now I would like to start with programming some smart contracts. I have some basic questions:

What is the best way to start?
How can I test my smart contracts?
Do I have to install a private net? If yes, where can I find a documentation about it?
Do you have any other useful advises for a newbie?

Thank you very much for your help

---

Thank you very much. This is very valuable information.

I created a contract according to the first video. When the contract is confirmed I get the following Message:

"No data is deployed on the contract address!"

What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

Setting up a private testnet is not necessary to commence on solidity programming. However in case you are interested in doing it, you can take a look at this blog: http://iotbl.blogspot.in/2017/03/setting-up-private-ethereum-testnet.html

You can commence solidity programming by writing a simple Dapp which fetches some hardcoded data from a SmartContract (say a SmartContract that just displays Hello World)?

If you are confused as to how to proceed with this, I would recommend watching these YoutTube videos to understand how it is done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_coM_g7Dbg&list=PLH4m2oS2ratdoHFEkGvwvd7TkeTv4sa7Z

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start with Solidity official documentation:

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick reference for getting started with a Javascript simple app. It includes a repo that uses some well known tools that can help you accelerate the curve.

Will also find some links to more advanced resources.

Hope it helps. I am also new to ethereum.

https://medium.com/@armova/javascript-dapps-with-ethereum-dadff55a7e04

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Truffle for testing and writing your contracts. http://truffleframework.com/docs

These videos helped me to get started and work out the development process using truffle:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jI1TuEaTro

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should first briefly go through the concept of bitcoin to be able to appreciate the beauty of this technology. You can do so by following the tutorials for bitcoin on Khan Academy.

For solidity tutorials, you can refer to this awesome free and interactive tutorial https://cryptozombies.io/

After doing that you should try to learn to use truffle and metamask. Medium has many good articles for the same.

Hope it helps